# How to Put Validation on SmartFilters?

Tags: sapui5

We have a SmartFilter bar and we are displaying two fields as default filter. We would like to put some validations on these. So for example user should at least enter some values in filter before hitting Go button.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

set `mandatory` property inside the `controlConfiguration` of SmartFilterBar

```
var oSmartFilterBar = new sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.SmartFilterBar({
    ...
    controlConfiguration:{
        ...
        mandatory : "mandatory",
        ...
        },
    ...
});
```

Read more about [controlConfiguration](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.ControlConfiguration.html#setMandatory)

Working example is [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfilterbar/preview).

Comment: Hi Sunil,I tried that but the problem is we would like to put the condition: Either first field or Second field must be entered . If I make both the fields Mandatory , I can not proceed with OR condition. In such case we will have to enter both the fields.

Answer (score 0):

There is an opportunity to subscribe to the FilterChange event. There you can do your validation. You can also find a better event if this one is to fine granular for you.
Code:

```
var yourEventHandlerMethod = function(event) {//your validation};
var oSmartFilterbar = this.getView().byId("smartFilterBar");
oSmartFilterbar.attachFilterChange(yourEventHandlerMethod);
```